# JPMS/Jigsaw Missing Main Class in Module

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, java-9, module-info

I'm trying to create a modular, executable jar file, that can be run with `java -p <jar file> -m <module>` on Java 9.0.1.

This works as expected when creating a jar with `jar cfe test.jar test.Main -C classes/ .`, but throws `module test does not have a MainClass attribute, use -m <module>/<main-class>` when generated with `mvn package` and `mvn assembly:single`.

These maven generated jars still work with `java -p test.jar -m test/test.Main`, and all the jars work on the classpath with `java -jar test.jar`.

---

I inspected the jar contents with `jar xf test.jar`, and found that the jars are exactly the same, except for the manifests (see below):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: test.Main
```

and

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: testuser
Build-Jdk: 9.0.1
Main-Class: test.Main
```

Notably, one still can't use `java -p test.jar -m test` when specifying the working manifest:

```
$ jar cfm test.jar test-contents/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C classes/ .
$ java -p test.jar -m test

module test does not have a MainClass attribute, use -m <module>/<main-class>
```

***Edit***: A repo with the expected behavior: https://github.com/deontologic/test

Comment: I'm using the latest (3.1.0) assembly plugin, but I don't think it's maven specific. I can only seem to create an executable jar when specifying the main class through `jar`

Comment: I'm unable to execute the jar without manually specifying the main class, in every case except when using jar's `--main-class` attribute.

Comment: @nullpointer I added a repo, hopefully the readme clarifies the expected behavior.

Comment: Well I guess the question is eventually why does `-m test` doesn't work while `-m test/test.Main` or `java -jar` does. Is it?

Comment: yes, precisely. What's so strange is that it works fine when using `jar --main-class`

Comment: Yes, they are different! The maven one is missing the ModuleMainClass specifier. The open issue is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-238 Thanks for the help!

Comment: Even I got that hint from the jmod tool description and then was certain from the code that there was an explicit mapping for the mainClass in descriptor as well.

Comment: The main thing to understand is the Main-Class attribute in the JAR manifest is for executable JARs (java -jar), it's not the same thing as the ModuleMainClass class file attribute in module-info.class. The jar tool sets both when you use the --main-class or -e options. The jar --manifest-file or -m options do not add or update the ModuleMainClass class file attribute when the manifest file contains the Main-Class attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't though find this in the [`jar` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#JSWOR614) documentation precisely either, yet the [`jmod` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm#GUID-0A0BDFF6-BE34-461B-86EF-AAC9A555E2AE__JDK9JLINKSTANDARDOPTIONS) defined it a little better.

> ```
> --main-class class-name
> ```
>
> Specifies main class to record in the module-info.class file.

I could further look into the JDK code and the behavior as you execute different commands seems related to the `mainClass` attribute of the [`ModuleDescriptor.mainClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#mainClass--).

Since when packaging the jar with `--main-class` flag, the entry in the module descriptor should be made to execute the module without specifying the fully qualified name of the main class during execution.

On the other hand this is not true [using the maven jar creation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-238) and might be fixed in future upgrades as found by you as well.

---

More on why the following works :

```
java -jar test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

If the `-jar` option is specified, then its argument is the name of the JAR file containing class and resource files for the application. The startup class must be indicated by the `Main-Class` manifest header in its manifest file(`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`)

and pretty obvious why specifying the fully qualified name works as:

```
java -p target/test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -m test/test.Main
```